# Erroneous sorting algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

So. I have tried to write an algorithm which sorts the elements of an array like this: elements smaller than a number given (called "a"), should be the first, and after them, the elements bigger or equal to the number called "a" and given in the console. It compiles and works, but not so ok. It should the result erronated and I can't figure out why. Thanks !

P.S: Sorry if I have something misspelled or if I have forgot something to add.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void MaiMici(int n, int s[], int a)
{
    int i,j;
    i=j=1;
    int temp;
    while(j<=n)
       {
        if (s[j]>a)
            j=j++;
        else
            temp=s[i];
            s[i]=s[j];
            s[j]=temp;
            i=i++;
            j=j++;
       }
}


int main()
{
    int s[100], n,a;

    cout<<"Da numarul a:";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Da dimensiunea: "; cin>>n;
    cout<<"Da vectorul: "<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Da s["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>s[i];
    }

    MaiMici(n,s,a);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<setw(2)<<s[i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Program terminat";

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as C if it is a C++ question?

Comment: `j = j++` is undefined behaviour, choose one of `j = j + 1` or plain `j++`.

Comment: you should clarify what you mean when you say it doesn't work very well. is the output incorrect? does it take an unexpectedly long time to execute?

Comment: You should use `std::sort` rather than writing your own.

Comment: You need `{ }` braces around your `else` block.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Not quite `std::sort`, just `std::partition`.

Comment: Still not working Daniel or M Oehm.

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @Ezek _I know that._ Sure?!?

Comment: Why return 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Because it simply does. Yea, I know what, but it won't solve my problem. Thanks !

Comment: @Ezek _"but it won't solve my problem."_ Fix undefined behavior in 1st place. Then you go for the next step. Learn how to use the debugger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least now it does something and it fixes a bunch of your problems. Still not sure exactly what behavior you are looking for from this though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void MaiMici(int n, int s[], int a) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int temp;

    while(j <= n) {
        if (s[j] > a)
            j++;
        else {
            temp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int s[100], n,a;

    cout<<"Da numarul a:";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Da dimensiunea: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Da vectorul: " << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout << "Da s[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> s[i];
    }

    MaiMici(n,s,a);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout << setw(2) << s[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "Program terminat";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look. If i enter in the array: 1,7,2,6,5 and I give number "a" value: 3. It should show 1,2,7,6,5. Hope you understand now.

Comment: The code I just posted for you works perfectly.